# SSRS Parameter - default to next business day

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, parameters, formula

What is the formula to default a parameter in SSRS to the next business day?

I know I can create code to calculate it, but I was hoping there was a single line of VB that I could use as a default to a parameter I am using in SSRS.

`=DateAdd("d",1,today())`    works if today is not Friday.

*It does not have to be fancy like taking into account holidays, but I would like it to default to Monday if today is a Friday.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to default to never have the next day be on a weekend you could use logic to account for 'if' statements like so:

```
=IIf( WeekdayName(Weekday(Today)) = "Friday", DateAdd("d", 3, today), 
 iif(WeekdayName(Weekday(Today)) = "Saturday", DateAdd("d", 2, today), 
 DateAdd("d", 1, today)))
```